# Will OS-Uninstaller delete my data?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, system-installation, boot-repair

I recently upgraded and currently I have 2 instances of Windows (1 in my HDD and the other in my newly bought SSD). Obviously I want to remove
Windows 10 from my HDD. Will doing that using [OS-Uninstaller](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OS-Uninstaller) format only that part or the will it format the entire disk? I don't want to lose my data.

Comment: Do you mean the Ubuntu installer?

Comment: @CarlH OS-Uninstaller is a component of Boot-Repair which civanakbas is apparently running in 18.04 because this question was tagged with the 18.04 tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OS-Uninstaller does not uninstall any other operating systems except for the OS that is selected to be uninstalled, but if you choose to uninstall an OS it will remove everything on that partition including the data. If you want to save any of the data that is stored on that partition then back it up before you uninstall the OS that is on that partition.

If you tell OS-Uninstaller to uninstall the Windows 10 that is installed on the HDD it will not uninstall the other Windows that is installed on the SSD. If there are multiple partitions on the HDD OS-Uninstaller will not delete any other partitions on the HDD except for the partition on which Windows 10 is installed.

After you finish removing Windows from the multiboot (or from a dual boot) using OS-Uninstaller run the `sudo update-grub` command to update GRUB.

If you are using a UEFI system, you may also need to remove the Windows entry from the UEFI firmware boot menu.