# Ubuntu remain on boot list after delete disk partition

Tags: bios, grub-efi

Recently I've installed Ubuntu 23.10 Minotaur Mantic in dual boot on a dedicated 500GB SSD alongside Windows boot loader, after some issues with my desired programs and Ubuntu version I decid downgrade to Linux Mint 21.2, everything is fine but I'm just curious why Ubuntu 23.10 partition still remain on boot list In my bios and how can I get rid of it?

You can see in this photo first boot device on list is Linux mint wich I use atm, 2nd is windows bootloader, 3rd is my last ubuntu 23.10 wich should be deleted, and 4th I have no ideea what it is.
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Delete the unwanted entry in your ESP; as you don't have Ubuntu installed any longer, you'll have to do it from within windows or linux mint (*which aren't on-topic on this site*).  As for why; that's how the EFI standard says EFI works; that data exists outside of the partition and within the drive's ESP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will OS-Uninstaller delete my data?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1293835/will-os-uninstaller-delete-my-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking for directories in `/boot/efi/EFI` (if it doesn't exist, look for subdirectories in `/boot/efi` with other names), backup (copy the folder) to any other partition, and delete the directory you suspect is Ubuntu's.

After that, reboot and check if it is still there. If it deleted a boot entry of another OS, restore your backup, and try it with another one.